# How to compare and sort nested Map in java based on Item price?

Tags: java, sorting, treemap, comparable, nested-map

How to fix this issue/error ( How to sort nested TreeMap in java)
When i am trying to sort Map using item price it is not working because TreeMap sort in natural order according to key but i need to sort this by using inner map key. any one help me..

```
public class SortedTest {

private static Map<Integer, Map<Item, Integer>> tm = new TreeMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Item item = new Item("beer", 1, 5.0);
    Item item1 = new Item("tofu", 2, 3.5);
    Item item2 = new Item("ic", 3, 3.2);
    Item item3 = new Item("mg", 4, 4.5);


    tm.put(item.getId(), new TreeMap<>());
    tm.get(item.getId()).put(item, 3);

    System.out.println(tm);

    tm.put(item1.getId(), new TreeMap<>());
    tm.get(item1.getId()).put(item1, 3);
    System.out.println(tm);

  } 
}
package trial;


public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
private String name;
private Integer id;
private Double price;

// constructor, setter & getter

@Override
public int compareTo(Item o) {
    if (getPrice() > o.getPrice()) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (price < o.getPrice()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            ", price=" + price +
            '}';
}
}
```

Comment: why are you using map of maps?

Comment: You are sorting each of the inner Maps by price. How would an ordering of the outer Map by price look like?

Comment: I am not able to figure out, if you can help me it would be nice of you,anyway thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to sort map by value, comparable method or comparator can do it with keys only.

Comment: my requirement is like that i need to sort using inner map i.e. value of outer map, thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Please,take a look at ValueComparator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values